# OpenVPN routing between different subnets

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, openvpn, openwrt

I have an issue with a complicated setup and I cannot wrap my head around it.

Please take a look at the drawing, it shows all involved components. Basically I am trying to NAT over two routers and one direction works, one doesn't.

Router 1 is an OpenWRT with two interfaces (lan and vpn) and Router 2 is a Ubuntu box.[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5xF8.jpg)

Router 1 is an OpenVPN client and connects to Router 2 (OpenVPN server). The OpenVPN subnet is 192.168.200.0/24, the internal LAN on the left side 192.168.170.0/24 and 10.0.0.10/24 on the other side. Router 2 is also dual-homed, the second interface exposes the OpenVPN server (10.10.0.1).

The OpenWRT forwards in both zones and also masquerades in both directions.

```
config defaults
        option input 'ACCEPT'
        option output 'ACCEPT'
        option forward 'ACCEPT'

config zone
        option name 'lan'
        option input 'ACCEPT'
        option output 'ACCEPT'
        option forward 'ACCEPT'
        option masq '1'
        option mtu_fix '1'
        option network 'lan'

config include
        option path '/etc/firewall.user'

config rule
        option target 'ACCEPT'
        option name 'Any - Any - All'
        option src '*'
        option dest '*'
        option proto 'all'

config zone
        option name 'vpn'
        option output 'ACCEPT'
        option input 'ACCEPT'
        option forward 'ACCEPT'
        option masq '1'
        option mtu_fix '1'
        option network 'OpenVPN'

config forwarding
        option dest 'lan'
        option src 'vpn'

config forwarding
        option dest 'vpn'
        option src 'lan'
```

The iptables config of Router 2 is as follows:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

And it also routes:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I am pushing the route to the network 192.168.170./24 on Router2.

```
route add -net 192.168.170./24 dev tun0
```

The outcome:

The left server 192.168.170.10 can ping the right server 10.0.0.10 and I have full connectivity from left to right.

Router 2 (192.168.200.1) can ping Router 1's VPN IP 192.168.200.7 and vice versa.
The right server 10.0.0.10 cannot ping the left one 192.168.170.10 and I have no connectivity from right to left - but I can ping Router 1's VPN IP 192.168.200.7.

And that's my problem. I need transparent masquerading in both directions. And I am not sure, where my problem is :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Made it work :)

Seems you not only need the route, but also a client directive on the OpenVPN server which pushes an internal route to OpenVPN (iroute)

Replace  with the common name in the certificate of the client and enable client directives in the server.conf of the OpenVPN server).

/etc/openvpn/ccd/

Content

```
ifconfig 192.168.200.7 255.255.255.0 #always configure client with static address
iroute 192.168.170.0 255.255.255.0 #behind this client is the subnet
```

See http://backreference.org/2009/11/15/openvpn-and-iroute/ :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna masquerading, then you have to specify a gateway for it!
Replace line `route add -net 192.168.170./24 dev tun0` with:

```
route add -net 192.168.170.0/24 gw 192.168.200.1
```

And vice versa...

Comment: I already tried that, but I cannot even route to the network :(

192.168.170.0   192.168.200.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0

Comment: I think your 10.0.0.10 machine doesn't have `tun0` interface. Add routing on that machine.
( Use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to solve the problem. )

Comment: Yes, the 10.0.0.10 has no tun0, and it only routes to its default gateway. The router should take care of this (Linux box). Thanks for your help! I will tcpdump this on both routers.